# composeObject function that catered to different number of arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function called composeObject, I use it a lot to compose objects from other objects, however I'm realizing that I write a lot of code in several scripts, and I would like to create a function that only works for all cases. Look how it is below:

```
const composeObject = (a, b, c, d, e, f) => Object.assign({}, a, b, c, d, e, f);
```

and I call her thus:

```
const Myobject =  composeObject(objA, objB, objC, objD, objE, objF);
```

the problem is that I have several different objects and sometimes I need to call it like this:

```
const Myobject1 =  composeObject(objA, objB);

// or 

const Myobject2 =  composeObject(objA, objB, objC, objD);
```

What I do to solve is:

```
const composeObject1 = (a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b);

const composeObject2 = (a, b, c, d) => Object.assign({}, a, b, c, d);
```

and I call them thus:

```
const Myobject1 =  composeObject1(objA, objB);

const Myobject2 =  composeObject2(objA, objB, objC, objD);
```

However, there are several objects, not just two, and this is getting tiresome. How would you write a composeObject function that catered to different number of arguments?

Comment: Side question: why do you need a separate function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REST syntax to achive the same result:

```js
const composeObject = (...objs) => Object.assign({},...objs);

let mergedObj = composeObject({a:1},{b:2});
let mergedObjTwo =  composeObject({a:1},{b:2},{c:5});

console.log(mergedObj);
console.log(mergedObjTwo);
```

Comment: Oops, I did not know these "...", what are they really doing? is bracing in a loop for "arguments.length"?

Comment: "..." These are what you call vargs.

Comment: It's not [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) syntax, it's just *rest* parameter syntax :-)

Comment: @PerduGames Yes, you could equivalently use the `arguments` object, but rest parameters have the advantage that they can come after other parameters and will be actual arrays.